# Problem with wi-fi. Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a problem with wifi connection on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. I have now two routers and two different wifi connections in my house. One of them is perfectly working on everything(2 PC's on Windows, 2 notebooks on Ubuntu 14.04, and smartphones). Its established on TP LINK TD W8968. The other new wifi connection also works on both PC's on Windows and also on every smartphone and I didnt have to do anything to make it work. Unfortunatelly it's not working on both notebooks. Can it be a problem with wireless lan controler? Both notebooks have Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless. This not working wifi is established on TP LINK TL -WR1042ND

Comment: to clarify you have some laptop your duel boot Windows and ubuntu, In windows wireless works but while in ubuntu wireless does not work?

Comment: No, I have two desktop computers with only Windows and two notebooks with only Ubuntu. And yes, wireless works in Windows but not in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Broadcom radio I recommend the following

hook up your laptop to an Ethernet cable to get it online.

Open a terminal and I want you to install this package:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/bcmwl

1. `sudo apt-get update`

(updates our package list)

1. `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

(installs the package itself)

This should only take a few minutes. Once done close all open programs and reboot. When your computer comes up wait a good 30 seconds and check the wireless using the network icon in the panel. If you don't see anything you may need to try toggling the wireless with a physical switch located on your laptop somewhere.

Comment: I already have bcmwl-kernel-source package installed so unfortunatelly this doesnt helo me